# Мусор в ofstream

Tags: c++

При использовании ofstream; в имени итогового файла возникает какой-то мусор, однако не понимаю причину этого. Были попытки делать 2 варианта функции и т.п., ничего не помогает

```
// Первый вариант:
char* getpathtofile(const char* filename) {
    char* path = new char[MAX_PATH];
    path[MAX_PATH] = '\0';
    memcpy(path+strlen(path), "\\some\\additional\\path\\filename.ps1", strlen("\\some\\additional\\path\\filename.ps1"));
    return path;
}

// Второй вариант
char* getpathtofile(const char* filename) {
    char* path = new char[MAX_PATH];
    path[MAX_PATH] = '\0';
    memcpy(path+strlen(path), "\\some\\additional\\path\\filename.ps1", strlen("\\some\\additional\\path\\filename.ps1"));
    char* returnpath = new char[strlen(path)+1];
    returnpath[strlen(path)] = '\0';
    returnpath = path;

    return path;
}

ofstream oFile(getpathtofile("connection.ps1"));
oFile.write("lorem ipsum").flush();
```

В итоге исполнения появляется файл.

```
Ожидание: connection.ps1
На деле получается: connection.ps10)sa (что-то подобное)
```

Comment: Вообще-то это, например, в VC++ просто не компилируется...

Comment: А зачем использовать ofstream, если вы пишете в стиле Си?  Или зачем не использовать преимущества С++, если вы пишете на С++?   Ну, чтобы вдруг не получалось ерундовая реализация, лучше просто данные занести в std::string

Comment: Сейчас попробую изменить в std::string. По поводу компиляции, позже изменил на memcpy, отредактирую

Comment: Очевидное решение со string и вправду помогло, спасибо. Не знаю почему не думал в этом направлении. Напишите как ответ @ARHovsepyan

Comment: Напомню за утечку памяти в втором варианте, в переменной `returnpath` лежит указатель на динамически выделенную память, а потом тут же переписывание указателя другой переменной, рекомендую совершить `delete[] returnpath;` до переписывания указателя

Comment: индексация массивов `new char[MAX_PATH]` => `[0] .. [MAX_PATH-1]`. А вы портите память сразу `path[MAX_PATH] = '\0';`